# Let $G=G_1\times G_2$, prove $G'=G_1'\times G_2'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm reading Hans Kurzweil's "The Theory of Finite Groups", in 1.6.2 (b) it's claimed that let $G=G_1\times G_2$, one has $G'=G_1'\times G_2'$ because:

> $$\begin{align}
> G'&=[G_1G_2,G_1G_2]\\
> &=\prod_{i,j}[G_i,G_j]\\
> &=G_1'\times G_2'.
> \end{align}$$

Here $G'$ is the commutator subgroup defined as
 $$G':= \langle [x,y] | x,y \in G\rangle,$$ and $$[x,y]:=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy.$$

---

However, I'm a bit confused here about the proof.

First, what does it mean by $\prod_{i,j}[G_i,G_j]$, is it $[G_1,G_1][G_1,G_2][G_2,G_1][G_2,G_2]$?

Second, why $[G_1G_2,G_1G_2]=\prod_{i,j}[G_i,G_j]$?

---

With $$G'=\langle [a_1b_1,a_2b_2] | a_1,a_2\in G, b_1, b_2 \in G_2 \rangle,$$  I can't move all $G_1$ part to the left side without changing the element $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$, because in general $a_1b_1\ne b_1a_1$.

Comment: I think the answers of the duplicate also explain your questions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde indeed. Than you!